# Running jetty server in multi module project

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jetty

I've been struggling this problem for like 5 hours now - I have multi module project and in one of the modules (RestManagement) I want to do REST API. Unfortunately whenever I try to run it all I get is bunch of errors.

In RestManagement module I have file HelloResource

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET @Path("/{name}") @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getMsg(@PathParam("name") String name) {

        return "hello: " + name;
    }
}
```

MyApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(HelloResource.class);
    }
}
```

and my module POM is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>oceniarka</artifactId>
        <groupId>oceniarka</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>RestManagement</artifactId>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oceniarka</groupId>
            <artifactId>DataManagament</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>RestManagement</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.3.v20140905</version>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

When I want to do mvn jetty:run though I get error

```
No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories
```

Even though I have it in my module POM. I also tried to run only this module with mvn -am -pl RestManagement jetty:run I get the same error.
I tried to put this plugin to main POM but then I got another errors. Beside scenarios I did describe here I did try like a fifty different ways to make it work but none of them help and right now I'm quite mad and hopeless
Hope someone can help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: wich repository u have in settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've figured this out so I'll post the answer for anyone who might look for it.
First of all, your jetty's build plugin should be in your REST module POM, secondly you should execute commands mvn clean, mvn install and mvn dependency:go-offline so your maven will download all your other modules to local repo (I'm not sure if you need all three commands but I guess it doesn't hurt to execute all of them just to be sure). Then you should run your desired maven command from console (mvn jetty:run in my case) in your module directory.
I'm not really sure what it doesn't work when I do

```
mvn -am -pl RestManagement jetty:run
```

but this way it worked for me. I hope it will work for you if you're having similar problem